# Authentication for an intra company's website in asp.net 5

Tags: asp.net5

i am working for a company which needs a web application that gives the complete information about the projects the company is handling or handled previously. for this they wanted mixed mode Authentication(only login.registering not allowed) for different levels of employees in the company working there. And the application should be developed using Asp.Net 5. I don't have fore-knowledge about Asp.Net Identity.Can anyone please Suggest Which type of authentication best suites my requirement?

Comment: what do you mean by mixed mode Authentication?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If (quoting) "registering not allowed", your only and the best option is windows authentication. You can use claims for different levels of employees.

[Claims authentication](https://leastprivilege.com/2015/07/21/the-state-of-security-in-asp-net-5-and-mvc-6-claims-authentication/)